# pass NSString to charValue

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, char

I am trying to pass a NSString value into a char type variable but I am receiving this error -

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f8dce60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x357ae56b 0x35a8e97f 0x357b24fb 0x357b0c0d 0x35702e68 0x3d233 0x379d1 0x31cd2ead 0x3633accb 0x37235 0x39851 0x370c1 0x36c33 0x331eb 0x363575b5 0x362a8991 0x362a88ad 0x31c11acf 0x31c111bb 0x31c39323 0x356f52e1 0x31c39783 0x31b9dc65 0x3577f143 0x3577e9a9 0x3577d6ef 0x356fbc1d 0x356fbaa9 0x385bf33b 0x36865535 0x26ffd 0x344c6b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I declare it in their h file like this

```
char storageChar;
//..
@property (assign) char storageIcon;
```

then in m I am calling a string from a NSDictionary entry and trying to pass it into the char like this

```
// initalize storageChar - char
    storageChar = [[tempDict valueForKey:@"STORAGE"] charValue];
```

once the thread runs this the app crashes, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong as there are no warnings or errors during the build...

Comment: A char is a single character. What are you trying to do with that variable.

Comment: NSString has no such method, so obviously it will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, as the error says, the `NSString` you get from `[tempDict valueForKey:@"STORAGE"]` does not respond to the method `charValue`. If you look in the documentation for `NSString` you won't find `charValue` anywhere. What you probably want is `[[tempDict valueForKey:@"STORAGE"] UTF8String]`, assuming you are using UTF-8 encoding in your `char` array. You also probably want to declare your char array as an array unless you mean that `storageIcon` is just a single character.

Why didn't you get a warning or error in the build? The problem is the compiler has no way of knowing what type of object will be returned from `[tempDict valueForKey:@"STORAGE"]`. So it just has to take your word for it that the object will respond to `charValue`. At runtime it discovers you are wrong and gives you an error. This is a standard pitfall of a very dynamic language like Objective-C.

Comment: ahh right I see why now.. I did not even check to see if charValue was a option on NSString because it didnt give me a warning.. which Is my mistake but now I know why which is helpful :) The NSString only has a single letter(char) so is using UTF8String still okay in tha instance?

Comment: actually using UTF8String is giving me this warning

 Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'const char *';

Comment: Fixed the issue, just had to chang my initilisation from **char mychar** to **const char *mychar** and its working perfectly, thanks for the help.